# How to plot pandas dataframe in 24 hour intervals? (multiple plots)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, time

I have a pandas dataframe of about 3 years with the resolution of 6 seconds and I want to group the data into 24-hour bins and plot each day **using matplotlib in a loop**.
This is my dataframe's head:

```
  timestamp                    consumption
0 2012-11-11 12:00:03          468
1 2012-11-11 12:00:09          476
2 2012-11-11 12:00:16          463
3 2012-11-11 12:00:22          449
4 2012-11-11 12:00:28          449
```

It includes the power consumption of a house from 2012 till 2015. After the pre-processing, the dataframe starts at about 12 pm of the first day. I need to plot all of the dataframe in 24-hour intervals and each plot must represent for a single day that starts from about 12 pm and ends at about 12 pm of the next day

So, I need about **1500 plots** that show the power consumption of **each day starting from 12 pm,** for about 1500 days of my dataframe.

Thanks in advance.

***Update:* The reason I want to plot 1500 days separately, is I want to check each night's power consumption and label the occupant's sleep pattern. And I considered each day from 12 pm to 12 pm to have a complete sleep cycle in one plot. And after preparing the labels I'll be able to use them as train and test data for classification**

Comment: You need 1500 plots (figures/pictures)?

Comment: @QuangHoang Exactly

Answer (score 0):

Consider this not only an answer but also a suggestion. First, convert the column 'timestamp' into the index (DatetimeIndex)

```
df.set_index(df['timestamp'], inplace=True, drop=True)
```

Then, get all the unique days that happen in your DataFrame

```
unique_days = list(set(df.index.to_period('D').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')))
```

We then squeeze the DataFrame into a Series

```
del df['timestamp']
df = df.squeeze()
```

Now, just plot unique days in your series in separate subplots.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

unique_days = list(set(df.index.to_period('D').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')))
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=len(unique_days), ncols=1)

row = 0
for day in unique_days:
    df[day].plot(ax=axes[row], figsize=(50,10))
    row += 1

plt.show()
```

[image: Plot for two sample days]

Now, it's time for you to play around with the parameters of [plots](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.plot.html?highlight=plot#pandas.Series.plot) so that you can customize them to your needs.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. I updated my question and I explained why I need 1500 plots separately. I tried your suggestion but I got this error:

ValueError: view limit minimum -36559.54999826389 is less than 1 and is an invalid Matplotlib date value. This often happens if you pass a non-datetime value to an axis that has datetime units

Comment: I see. Could you show the output of df.head()?
I suspect the column df['timestamp'] hasn't been deleted.
Try the edited version.

Comment: I added **plot.show()** to the last line of the loop. It plotted but it wasn't for a single day. It was for several days.

Comment: @Arash.Ch - please check if the new version of my answer is what you were looking for. If so, please mark as the accepted answer. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of a strange request. If we knew what your end objective is, it might be easier to understand, but I'm going to assume you want to plot and then save figures for each of the days.

```
df['day'] = (df['timestamp'] + pd.Timedelta('12h')).dt.date
for day in df['day'].unique():
    mask = (df['day'] == day)
    #<the code for the plot that you want>
    plt.plot(x=df[mask]['timestamp'].dt.time,y=df[mask]['consumption'])
    plt.savefig('filename'+str(day)+'.png')
    plt.close()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering my question. I updated my question and I explained why I need 1500 plots separately. I tried your code but it saved empty plots.

Comment: How many plots does the code produce? Have you tried the filter on its own? E.g. typing just `df[mask]` and check the outputs.

Comment: I think I know what may have happened, the edit above may fix it.

Comment: after saving 130 plots, I stopped the process. Because it was saving empty plots. It saved from **filename2012-11-11.png** to **filename2013-04-16.png**. But even if the plots were not empty, your code is ploting day by day based on the date. So the data will be plotted from 00:00:00 to 23:59:59 in each plot. But I need the days to be from 12 pm to 12 pm.

Comment: Added a bit more to meet those other requirements. Day should be a time offset of 12 hours now.